# Response object scala.Unit

Tags: scala, scalatra

I have an action that returns `Unit`:

```
post("/settings") {
      blahblahblah...
      Unit
    }
```

Previously, the client received an empty response.

But after I upgraded the Scalatra version from 2.5.0 to 2.7.1 and Java from 8 to 11, the response now contains the following text:

```
object scala.Unit
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please clarify _"the object scala.Unit became the client in the body"_ ?

Comment: Inside the response, Chrome shows object scala.Unit...

Answer (score 3):

Return the `Unit` value `()` instead of the `Unit` companion object (which has type `Unit.type` and is not an instance of type `Unit`).

```
post("/settings") {
  blahblahblah...
  ()
}
```

In scala 2.13 your code simply would not compile anymore. You get an error:

```
`Unit` companion object is not allowed in source; instead, use `()` for the unit value
```

Comment: Why did returning Unit work correctly before?

Comment: I don't know scalatra. Perhaps type `Unit` was inferred for some reason, which causes value `()` to be inserted by the compiler.

Comment: Hm... Its worked, but I still don't understand why it worked earlier, but now it doesn't=( If I'm not mistaken, then () =Unit